# VFR output from muxer-level concatenation of CFR inputs

Tags: ffmpeg

I used this command for concatenating 2 constant rate videos:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt  -c copy output.mp4
```

where the file `files.txt` has this content:

```
file input1.mp4
file input2.mp4
```

I'm wondering why the *output* file has a *variable frame rate*, even though both *input* files has a *constant* one?

---

Part of MediaInfo for every *input* file:

```
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
```

and for the *output* file:

```
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 29.905 FPS
Minimum frame rate                       : 19.224 FPS
Maximum frame rate                       : 30.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
```

---

FFprobe outputs:

```
>ffprobe -hide_banner input1.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.22.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.95, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2649 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2394 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn
, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 258 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

---

```
>ffprobe -hide_banner input2.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.22.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.95, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2649 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2394 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn
, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 258 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

---

```
>ffprobe -hide_banner output.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.22.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2647 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2386 kb/s, 29.90 fps, 60 tbr, 15360
tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 257 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Comment: Share the ffprobe output for both files and the output

Comment: @Gyan, I added it now.

Comment: Does `ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt  -c copy -an output.mp4` yield a CFR output?

Comment: @Gyan, no, the output is still VFR.

Comment: @Gyan Were you able to find out the cause? I'm facing the exact same problem. It appears to be related to audio. -an on contact doesn't change anything, but if I remove audio from both files before concat framerate becomes constant.